# Firebase: snap.child(...).once is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to listen to some data from my firebase but I first have to check if the keys leading to the specific data has already been made. If they have not yet been made there is no problem I don't have to listen.

I get this error message:

> snip.child(...).once is not a function

I have tried to just followed their documentation from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#child) it really seems as if what I am doing should be legal.

The `.hasChild(...)` works fine.

```js
rootRef.child('match-feed-comments').once('value', snip => {
    if (snip.hasChild(this.props.matchId)) { // Checking if child exists
        snip.child(this.props.matchId).once('value', snup => { // if the child exists we listen
            if (snup.hasChild(this.props.feedComponentId)) {
                snup.child(this.props.feedComponentId).on('value', snap => {
                    // finally I want to do stuff with the data
                    this.setState({
                        comments: snap.val()
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to use `once` and the `value` event with snapshots. Snapshots already have all of the data. Just call `val` on the snapshot returned by `child`.

Comment: @cartant Unless you want to post that as an answer, I vote to close this as a "typo".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, it's pretty much a typo. I've voted to close it as such.